# Dar formato a una cadena XML

Tags: c#, xml

Normalmente hago lo siguiente:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("htts://example.com/documento.xml");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ruta\mixml.xml", document.OuterXml);
```

y al abrir el archivo, el resultado es que obtengo el xml en una sola linea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><item><data><url>url01</url><files><file>file01</file><file>file02</file></files></data></item>
```

No existen espacios entre lineas dificultando la lectura cuando se trata de documentos muy largos.

Usando Json.NET existe una opción para darle formato a un json con `Formatting.Indented`

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.Indented);
```

¿Existe una opción para dar formato de Indentación a un XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
  <data>
    <url>url01</url>
    <files>
      <file>file01</file>
      <file>file02</file>
    </files>
  </data>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día compañero, te comento que la solución se encuentra en la comunidad en inglés, ya estabas muy cerca con lo del `Formatting.Indented`, el link:

[Format XML String to Print Friendly XML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string)

El código que mas te servirá de las respuestas dentro del link:

Tendrá que analizar el contenido de alguna manera... Encuentro que usar LINQ es la forma más fácil de hacerlo. Una vez más, todo depende de su escenario exacto. Aquí hay un ejemplo de trabajo que usa LINQ para formatear una cadena XML de entrada.

```
string FormatXml(string xml){
     try{
         XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
         return doc.ToString();
     }catch (Exception){
         // Maneja y muestra si hay alguna excepción fatal acá
         return xml;
     }
 }
```

> Créditos: [Charles Prakash Dasari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129196/charles-prakash-dasari)

Solo te pido por favor, que busquemos un poco mas, al inicio cuesta un poco, ya después uno sabe como buscar mejor. Cualquier adicional a la orden

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: si vas a usar la respuesta de alguien mas, debes traducirla y colocar todo lo importante aqui, para darle créditos al autor original; solo responder con links es de baja calidad

Comment: Listo @shadow, gracias por tus consejos. Saludos cordiales

Comment: muchas gracias, esto lo solicionó